# Save sql code used for creating database

Tags: mysql, sql, save

I am using windows terminal to create a simple database. I was wondering is the code used saved anywhere or do I have to save it? And how? I need to save the code I used for creating the database that's why I'm asking.

Comment: "windows terminal"? What DBMS?

Comment: From your responses, I added a `mySql` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about SQL Server, you can script out the database you created - just right click on the database in Management Studio, and script away!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should save your work. Most tools don't save your indentation, they often format the sql in their own way - sometimees as

```
CREATE TABLE user@host.dbname.table AS ...
```

so it works to reconstruct your database, but isn't well readable. The worst thing I ever saw was what MsAccess did to my Input in the SQL-Window (but it was 15 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx` to see the definition for your table(s).

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysqldump` can help you create an sql file which you can later run to create a DB identical to yours.
It has many useful options you can read about [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

For your case it seems you need the schema only, without the data - see a how-to [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysqldump-schema-only/). Basically all you need is the command:
`mysqldump --no-data -u Username -pPassword mydatabase`